# Ctypes definition

Tags: python, ctypes

How could I write the definition copied bellow using ctypes?

```
unsigned char* x = new unsigned char[10];
```

Thank you.

Comment: ctypes is used for interop. You need to describe how the parameters are passed. But char* typically maps to `c_char_p`.

Comment: This question was part of a previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513269/calling-dll-functions-using-python-ctypes). Thank you.

Comment: Your questions (this one and the previous one) make no sense whatsoever. You don't need to use ctypes when converting C code to Python. You need ctypes when you want to call native code from Python. Where's the native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you need to use `x`, you probably want `ctypes.create_string_buffer`.

```
x = ctypes.create_string_buffer(' ' * 10);
```